# Find Rows whose date range contain a given date

Tags: sql, mysql

I am looking at the following problem:

My group table contains two fields: ArrivalDate and DepartureDate.

Now I want to find all groups who are present at a given date.

Eg. the SQL query is passed a date, and I want to find every group where this date falls into the range ArrivalDate to DepartureDate.

Thanks a lot!
Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  yourGroupTable as y
WHERE
  Curdate() BETWEEN y.ArrivalDate AND y.DepartureDate
```

replace Curdate() by your actual date value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know that one could swap the WHERE and BETWEEN parameters, meaning that WHERE does not always have to be followed by a column name!